# Delete structure data from text file in C

Tags: c, function, data-structures, structure, file-handling

I took input from the user and stored in a structure then wrote them to txt file using

```
fwrite(&a[i],sizeof(a[i]),1,file);
```

Now what I want to do is delete specific index data of the structure stored in the file.
Here's what I tried doing.

```
void deletespecific()
{
    int delroll;
    printf("ENTER THE ROLL NUMBER TO DELETE: ");
    scanf("%d",&delroll);
    readdata();  //reads all data stored in the file
    file=fopen("Records.txt","w");
    for (int w=0;w<t;w++)
    {
        if(a[w].roll!=delroll)
        {
            fwrite(&a[w],sizeof(a[w]),1,file);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf(Green"DATA SUCCESSFULLY DELETED!\n"Reset);
 }
```

I first read all the data stored in the file into the structure then wrote them into the file only if the roll wasnot equal to the roll to be deleted.

**The problem I'm having is that every time I run the function "deletespecific" it deletes the last indexed data.**

And this is just the readdata function:

```
void readdata()
{
    t=0;
    file=fopen("Records.txt","r");

    while(fread(&a[i],sizeof(a[i]),1,file)==1)
    {
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't have i initialized as 0 in the readdata.
This is the updated readdata function:

```
void readdata()
{
    i=0;
    t=0;
    file=fopen("Records.txt","r");

    while(fread(&a[i],sizeof(a[i]),1,file)==1)
    {
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Incase you need the full code:
[fullcode](https://github.com/BijanRegmi/finalproject)

Comment: In `readdata()`, why the two counters `i` and `t`? Why are they global? Why do you not initialize `i`?

Comment: When asking for debugging help, be sure to post a complete set of code. If we can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you with the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: Depending on the operating system, you may need to use `"rb"` and `"wb"` in the `fopen` call.

Comment: Is `t` a global variable?

Comment: "The problem I'm having is that every time I run the function "deletespecific" it deletes the last indexed data." How do you see that?

Comment: how is `a[]` being declared, so it is large enough to hold the whole file?

Comment: What is `i`? A global variable that isn't set to zero when starting a new read?

Comment: in the `readdata()` function, `i` is unrelated to anything.  Suggest replacing all references to `i` with `t`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp as you said I initialized i in readdata and the problem is fixed now.

Comment: https://github.com/BijanRegmi/finalproject  this is the full. It's workine fine now.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `t`, a global variable, is the offset (starts with 0) into the array `a[]`.

Therefore, its' contents is 1 less than the number of entries in the `a[]` array rather than the number of entries in the `a[]` array.